# Placing large image in Word Online not working

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to place a large jpg image (size 17.15 MB) in Word Online. The code appears that the image was placed successfully, but it doesn't place the image in the document and there are no error messages. It is working properly in Word Desktop.

```
let options = {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image};
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(base64, options, function(obj){
  console.log('obj', obj)
  context.sync().then(function(){
    console.log('complete')
  }, function(err){
    if(err){console.log('failed')}
  });
});
```

obj is returning:

```
status: "succeeded"
value: {}
```

The code places properly for a smaller image and on Desktop. Is there another way to check if the image placed properly or an error message?

Comment: Sorry that we can't repro this issue. Can you please share your wacsessionid and that image with us? You can pick up a way you like to share (or we can provide an email address for you).
Btw, considering we may spend some time in communication, one suggestion for you is to submit this issue to our github channel, here is the link https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues

Comment: Thanks @Jinghui-MSFT, can you provide me with an email address?

Comment: The same issue with https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3033. Please go to GitHub for details.